# Invalid entity passed while trying below method

Tags: eclipse, csv, import, upload, karate

Uploading a csv file using post request in eclipse karate.

```
Feature: attachment

  Scenario: read the csv file
    Given url 'url'
    And header Authorization = 'zxcvbnsdfghrtyu'
    And multipart file file = ('classpath:datasets/xxx.csv') **file I need to attach**
    * form field entity = 'xxxx'
   
    When method POST
    And print response
    Then status 201
```

> Payload:

importfile: (binary) ---> **this carries the csv file (how do i use this in karate framework)**
entity: xxx
charencoding: UTF-8
delimiter: ,
duplicate_handling: skip

CSV file which i need to upload is in system and in feature file under datasets

Tried: Uploading a CSV file

````
Things I tried:

1. ```
    And multipart file file = ('classpath:datasets/xxx.csv')
    * form field entity = 'xxx'
````

2. 

- form field importfile = 'customer.csv'

  - form field entity = 'xxx'

````
3. ```
And multipart file file = {value:'/hii/src/test/java/datasets/customer.csv',filename:'customer.csv',contentType:'application/csv'}
 * form field entity = 'xxx'
````

Getting error as invalid Entity Passed.